# How can I scroll to an element with sticky positioning?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, sticky

I have the following code and I want to use ids to switch between slides, but with an id it doesn't work and als with JS scrollTo, scrollIntoView and other variations.
It works on the way down but not up.

I try to make a website which overlaps with itself and creates a nice progressive flow for surveys.
It should also be able to move to a previous slide, so you can enter or change some answer in such a survey.

I hope you can help me and maybe see something which i didn't see.

```js
// set color for each slide
window.onload = function() {
    let slides = [...document.getElementsByClassName("slide")];
    for(let n in slides) {
        let slide = slides[n];
        slide.style.backgroundColor = "hsl("+((360 / slides.length) * n)+", 100%, 25%)";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    font-size: 3vw;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#ref {
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#ref a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.slide {
    background-color: #404050;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
    height: calc(100vh - 2px);
    left: 0;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: calc(100vw - 2px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="ref">
            <a href="#s1">S1</a>
            <a href="#s2">S2</a>
            <a href="#s3">S3</a>
            <a href="#s4">S4</a>
            <a href="#s5">S5</a>
            <a href="#s6">S6</a>
            <a href="#s7">S7</a>
            <a href="#s8">S8</a>
            <a href="#s9">S9</a>
        </div>
        <div id="s1" class="slide">
            <h1>Slide 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="s2" class="slide">
            <h1>Slide 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="s3" class="slide">
            <h1>Slide 3</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="s4" class="slide">
            <h1>Slide 4</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="s5" class="slide">
            <h1>Slide 5</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="s6" class="slide">
            <h1>Slide 6</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="s7" class="slide">
            <h1>Slide 7</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="s8" class="slide">
            <h1>Slide 8</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="s9" class="slide">
            <h1>Slide 9</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just as a side note: `for(let n in slides)` has to be `for(let slide of slides)` for array iteration.

Comment: I know but I need the index to generate the hue and so each color

Comment: that is also a possible way but I think my way is also ok, right? But do you have an idea how I can skip to another slide?

Comment: Then use `for(let [n, slide] of slides.entries())`. Sorry, I f/&%$ed up the syntax.

Comment: No problem. :) .

Comment: I can't see any differences in behaviour between the snippet in your question and the snippet in the accepted answer. What you have already seems to work perfectly. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: The problem was that i could click on a link that takes me futher down but if i click a higher one i didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a long time I found a solution but it is very specific.

You need to have a parent element which only includes the slides (in this case it is `main`), then you need to give the parent element a height and an overflow auto.

After those steps add the javascript, which gets the selected element and its parent (here again `main`), then calculates the average height per element, after that it gets the index of the elem relative to the parent and multiplies it with the height to get the scrollOffset, which is in the last step set for the parent.

```js
// set color for each slide
window.onload = function() {
    let slides = [...document.getElementsByClassName("slide")];
    for(let n in slides) {
        let slide = slides[n];
        slide.style.backgroundColor = "hsl("+((360 / slides.length) * n)+", 100%, 25%)";
    }
}

window.onhashchange = function() {
    let hash = document.body.querySelector(location.hash);
    let parent = hash.parentElement;
    let scrollOffset = parent.scrollHeight / parent.childElementCount;
    scrollOffset *= Array.prototype.indexOf.call(parent.children, hash);
    parent.scrollTop = scrollOffset;
}
```

```css
body {
    font-size: 3vw;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#ref {
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#ref a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

main {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}

.slide {
    background-color: #404050;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
    height: calc(100vh - 2px);
    left: 0;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: calc(100vw - 2px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="ref">
            <a href="#s1">S1</a>
            <a href="#s2">S2</a>
            <a href="#s3">S3</a>
            <a href="#s4">S4</a>
            <a href="#s5">S5</a>
            <a href="#s6">S6</a>
            <a href="#s7">S7</a>
            <a href="#s8">S8</a>
            <a href="#s9">S9</a>
        </div>
        <main>
            <div id="s1" class="slide">
                <h1>Slide 1</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="s2" class="slide">
                <h1>Slide 2</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="s3" class="slide">
                <h1>Slide 3</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="s4" class="slide">
                <h1>Slide 4</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="s5" class="slide">
                <h1>Slide 5</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="s6" class="slide">
                <h1>Slide 6</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="s7" class="slide">
                <h1>Slide 7</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="s8" class="slide">
                <h1>Slide 8</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="s9" class="slide">
                <h1>Slide 9</h1>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely loved the implentation. Such small css and so powerful effect.

But seems like Browser don't do the # magic with sticky elements. Although this could have been solved with JS, but thought of having a HTML-CSS solution to it by a little tweak in the HTML (adding an extra static element for # reference). Hope you like the solution.

```js
// set color for each slide
window.onload = function() {
    let slides = [...document.getElementsByClassName("slide")];
    for(let n in slides) {
        let slide = slides[n];
        slide.style.backgroundColor = "hsl("+((360 / slides.length) * n)+", 100%, 25%)";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    font-size: 3vw;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#ref {
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#ref a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.slide {
    background-color: #404050;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
    height: calc(100vh - 2px);
    left: 0;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: calc(100vw - 2px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="ref">
            <a href="#s1">S1</a>
            <a href="#s2">S2</a>
            <a href="#s3">S3</a>
            <a href="#s4">S4</a>
            <a href="#s5">S5</a>
            <a href="#s6">S6</a>
            <a href="#s7">S7</a>
            <a href="#s8">S8</a>
            <a href="#s9">S9</a>
        </div>
        <div id="s1"> </div><!--Extra static element for # reference-->
          <div class="slide">
            <h1>Slide 1</h1>
          </div>
        
        <div id="s2"></div><!--Extra static element for # reference-->
          <div class="slide">
            <h1>Slide 2</h1>
          </div>
        
        <div id="s3"></div><!--Extra static element for # reference-->
          <div class="slide">
            <h1>Slide 3</h1>
          </div>
        
        <div id="s4"></div><!--Extra static element for # reference-->
          <div class="slide">
            <h1>Slide 4</h1>
          </div>
        
        <div id="s5"></div><!--Extra static element for # reference-->
          <div class="slide">
            <h1>Slide 5</h1>
          </div>
        
        <div id="s6"></div><!--Extra static element for # reference-->
          <div class="slide">
            <h1>Slide 6</h1>
          </div>
        
        <div id="s7"></div><!--Extra static element for # reference-->
          <div class="slide">
            <h1>Slide 7</h1>
          </div>
        
        <div id="s8"></div><!--Extra static element for # reference-->
          <div class="slide">
            <h1>Slide 8</h1>
          </div>
        
        <div id="s9"></div><!--Extra static element for # reference-->
          <div class="slide">
            <h1>Slide 9</h1>
          </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice word and a big thanks for your solution. I will try to implement it and if it works you will notice.

Comment: I just noticed that the sticky effect is lost by the change, but mybe your solution could still work

Comment: Updated the solution. just added an empty div.

Comment: I actually posted this solution with empty div in the first place... but edited the solution for cleaning it.